# Особенности конкретных имен существительных

Tags: морфология

Могут ли конкретные имена существительные обозначать понятия, которые нельзя ощутить, потрогать и т.д. (например, слово правило, пример), которые при этом сочетаются и с определенно-количественными числительными (два / три примера, правила)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш вопрос не вполне понятен, так как вы сами в нем привели примеры именно таких случаев: "два примера", "три правила".

Конкретные имена существительные обозначают считаемые объекты и понятия. Среди них множество нематериальных понятий: слово, фраза, предложение, митинг, профессия, решение... Их тысячи.

**Все без исключения** конкретные существительные сочетаются с определенно-количественными числительными. Вообще говоря, определенно-количественные числительные не сочета­ются только с вещественными и отвлеченными существительными. Сочетаемость с определенно-количественными числительными - одно из ключевых отличий конкретных существительных от отвлеченных.